# Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{n^2} \int_0^n \frac{ \sqrt{n^2-x^2} }{2+x^{-x}} dx$

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

I need to calculate the limit$$\lim_{n \to  \infty }  \frac{1}{n^2}  \int_0^n  \frac{ \sqrt{n^2-x^2} }{2+x^{-x}} dx$$
How could I calculate this? Any hlep would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm. looks like one has to use Lebesgue monotone convergence/ dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Outline:**

- First, do the change of variable $x=ny$, to get
  $
  \int_0^1 f_n(y) dy
  $
  with $$f_n(y) = \frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{2+e^{-ny \ln (ny)}}.$$
- Then, compute the pointwise limit $f$ of $f_n$ on $(0,1]$.
- Finally, apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem to show that $\int_0^1 f_n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \int_0^1 f$.

Comment: I think you mean $x=ny$, you have it backwards.

Comment: True, thanks. Fixed it. Also, for the sake of checking at the end: the answer is $\frac{\pi}{8}$.

Comment: I think for explicitness you have still to show that $f_n$ is bounded uniformly by an $\mathscr L^1$ function, and I don't think it would suffice to have only pointwise convergence to an $\mathscr L^1$.  Please correct me if you find my argument is off.

Comment: Well, the last part is to apply the DCT. For that, you have to show that indeed $f_n$ is bounded by an integrable function -- that's part of applying the theorem... but showing $0\leq f_n \leq f$ isn't too much of a hassle. The second part is basically saying: "if $\int f_n$ converges, the candidate is $\int f$. The last part is "applying the DCT to show that there is convergence indeed." @Vim

Answer (score 0):

Try $u=x/n$. It'll get rid of most of the horrible places where $n$ appears. All that's left to do is figure out the limit in the denominator, where you get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(nu)^{-nu}$$